# Automated build Hudson/SVN

Tags: svn, build, hudson

There is an `Hudson version 2.2.1` set up and running build upon a subversion. I now want to automate the build process where if a user commits to the svn a build automatically takes place and send an email id if the build fails. But it requires editing `post commit` hooks. Is there any other way of achieving the same without using `svn hooks`?

-sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without post commit hooks, the only way that hudson can be notified of a change is through polling the svn server.

The [Subversion plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Subversion+Plugin) supports setting up a polling schedule (cron format- ex: every minute).

Comment: I have updated the question based on your answer but i get authentication failed message. But by using this option does build happen `only if changes` are there in the repository ?

Comment: you normally don't update questions to ask new ones :) If the polling question is covered you should accept the answer. Best is to create a new question for the authentication so people can take a look at it.